# C# GoogleAPI - How to set a time duration when variable type is "object"?

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, firebase-test-lab

I'm stuck with my problem using " Google.Apis.Testing.v1.Data " and their documentation doesn't help me.

I have to set a "timeout" value (= a duration), but the variable type is "object" instead of "float" for example. I tried to put an int, a float, and a string but that doesn't work.

The object API doc is [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/testing/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Testing_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1TestSpecification.html#a15d48997ad5ff3203767e9bcf810e40c). My variable is "TestTimeout" which is definitely a duration.

When I searched for a solution, I saw in java the variable type is string but that doesn't help ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/master/clients/google-api-services-testing/v1/1.29.2/com/google/api/services/testing/model/TestSpecification.java))

Just for your information, I'm using this lib to execute my android application on their test devices. It's a service called TestLab in Firebase. The timeout value needs to be higher because I don't have enough time to execute my test. Here is my code, everything is working well besides this TimeOut.

```
        TestMatrix testMatrix = new TestMatrix();

        testMatrix.TestSpecification = new TestSpecification();
        testMatrix.TestSpecification.TestTimeout = 600.0f; // I tested 600, 600.0f, "600", "30m", "500s"

        testMatrix.EnvironmentMatrix = new EnvironmentMatrix();
        testMatrix.EnvironmentMatrix.AndroidDeviceList = new AndroidDeviceList();
        testMatrix.EnvironmentMatrix.AndroidDeviceList.AndroidDevices = new List<AndroidDevice>();

        foreach (TestMatrixModel.TestData testData in _model.ListTests)
        {
            if (testData.IsSelected)
            {
                //Here I'm using my own data class to set GoogleAPI objects, it's simple
                //as it asks me strings even for integer numbers, and it's working
                foreach (int indice in testData.ChosenAndroidVersionsIndices)
                {
                    AndroidDevice device = new AndroidDevice();

                    device.AndroidModelId = testData.ModelID;
                    device.AndroidVersionId = testData.AvailableAndroidVersions[indice];
                    device.Locale = testData.AvailableLocales[testData.ChosenLocale];
                    device.Orientation = testData.Orientation;

                    testMatrix.EnvironmentMatrix.AndroidDeviceList.AndroidDevices.Add(device);
                }
            }
        }
```

Ok and here is the result of the request :

```
    {
  "testMatrixId": "matrix-2dntrwio3kco7",
  "testSpecification": {
    "testTimeout": "300s",
    "testSetup": {},
    "androidTestLoop": {
      "appApk": {
        "gcsPath": "gs://myLinkIntoGoogleCloudStorage.apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "environmentMatrix": {
    "androidDeviceList": {
      "androidDevices": [
        {
          "androidModelId": "grandpplte",
          "androidVersionId": "23",
          "locale": "en_001",
          "orientation": "landscape"
        },
        {
          "androidModelId": "hero2lte",
          "androidVersionId": "23",
          "locale": "en_001",
          "orientation": "landscape"
        },
etc.....
```

As you can see, it seems to be a string set to "300s"... so why "500s" cannot enter in ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the error you are encountering when e.g. using "500s". From the [generated sourcse](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Testing.v1/Google.Apis.Testing.v1.cs) it looks like it should accept a string. Is the error a compile-time error, or an error when you make the request?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got my answer :

```
testMatrix.TestSpecification.TestTimeout = "600s";
```

So it was a string and needed to finish with "s". Why that didn't work when I tried ? Just because my code was overrided with another TestSpecification after... my bad.